# Hide div on blur or mouse out

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

Trying to hide a div after it loses focus or on blur. I have a simple form and am providing some guidelines to users when the focus on the field either by touch or click (this is a site for mobile). It is working as I would like for show, but I have to click on the field again to get the div to hide again.

HTML:

```
 <input type="text" id="usernameCL" name="usernameCL" placeholder="Create a Username" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" class="field_hints"/>
<div id="usernameCL" class="tooltip_static" style="display:none"> This be my field hint</div>
```

This be my other field hint

JQuery Function using 1.6.4 JQ:

```
$().ready(function () {
    $('.field_hints').bind('focus',
     function()
     {
       var field = this.id;
       var div = $('.tooltip_static[id='+field+']');

       if(div.css('display') == 'none')
       {
         div.show(function()
         {
           div.slideUp("fast");
         });
       }
      else
      {
        div.hide('blur');
      }
    });
  });
```

And here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LapPA/

Anyone know how to get this to hide on blur or mouse out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a separate handler bound to the `blur` event.

For example, you could do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LapPA/6/):

```
$().ready(function () {
  $('.field_hints').bind('focus',
    function()
    {
      var field = this.id;
      var div = $('.tooltip_static[id='+field+']');

      if(div.css('display') == 'none')
      {
        div.hide(function()
        {
          div.slideDown("fast");
        });
      }
    }).bind('blur', 
        function()
        {
            var field = this.id;
            var div = $('.tooltip_static[id='+field+']');
            div.hide();
        });
  });
```

Comment: That actually works pretty well and with iOS Next button on form. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('#myformid').on('blur', '.field_hints',function(){
     $(this).next('.tooltip_static').hide();
 }); //replace #myformid with the id of your form
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) event: http://jsfiddle.net/4VUvD/

```
$().ready(function () {
      $('.field_hints').bind('focus', function() {
          var field = this.id;
          var div = $('.tooltip_static[id='+field+']');
          div.slideDown("fast");
      }).bind('mouseleave', function(){
          $('.tooltip_static[id='+this.id+']').slideUp("fast");
      });
});
```

Comment: That worked good. Some issues with using the Next button on iOS but assume I need to compensate for tab out.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have two objects with the same id `usernameCL`. This is NOT good.

The code you are searching for:

```
var func = function () {
    // We assume the id of the input tag to be #someid, and the tooltip div to be #someid_tooltip
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + id + '_tooltip').fadeOut();
};

$('#usernameCL').bind('blur', func);
$('#usernameCL').bind('mouseout', func);
```

Could be that I messed up a name or two.

Comment: yeah that's my bad. used the wrong id. I'll change it. Basically if you see how this div opens up below our comment box, that is what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Actually I noticed that too and was wondering why it was working since I was re-using the ID. I guess I can try using a class instead.

Comment: Classes are supposed to be used for assigning similar/same `_traits_ to multiple tags. Using them for identification is not a good idea (but it does work if you give care, for example with the other examples using `$(this).next()`). That's what ids are for.